# Converting mysql timestamp to actual time mm dd yyyy hh mm from Code igniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Im trying to get the mysql timestamp to go to actual time. The PHP code im using though code igniter echos out the pub date for news articles but, its in this format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss I want it in MM/DD/YY HH:MM the code echos it out after running a query from a controller here is the code from the view `<?php echo $row->pubdate; ?>` pubdate is the column name from the MYSQL database. I've looked around stack overflow for an answer to this but I have not been able to find anything that works for my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a function which takes a MySQL formatted date and returns the format you want, something like this:

```
function nice_date($mysql_date)
{
    list($date,$time) = explode(" ",$mysql_date);
    list($year,$month,$day) = explode("-",$date);
    return $month.'/'.$day.'/'.$year.' '.$time;
}
```

Use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split the given date into `$date` and `$time` variables (using [list](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) to assign the variables), then split `$date` into year, month and day. Then simply return a string with the variables reordered.

Comment: Okay I got all of that, and i belive I loaded my function in my controller by using this `$this->load->niceDate;` I still don't know how to get it into my view thought I tried this `<?php echo $row->pubdate->niceDate; ?>&nbsp;</br>` but I got an error Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Where did you put the `nice_date` (sorry, I renamed it!) function?

Comment: So in the view, try `echo $this->HomeModel->nice_date($row->pubdate);`

Comment: Yep it worked! Thanks for the help